# BLOB cache not invalidating consistently across farm

Tags: 2013, document-library, versioning, sharepoint-on-prem, blob-cache

Farm with 9 WFEs - 6 on primary site, 3 in DR (stretched farm). BLOB cache is enabled on all WFEs.

Have some JS files in the Style Library sub-folder. Versioning with major versions enabled, no approval required. No publishing feature enabled (site or web).

The issue: all the servers in primary location return oldest (first) version of the JS files, while all WFEs in DR return the latest one. Therefore, changing the files doesn't cause BLOB cache invalidation on the primary site WFEs....

Other things already tried:

- added timestamps to JS file URLs
- disabled the Minimal download strategy
- tested in IE and Chrome + cleared browser cache

Any clues what is happening here?

Comment: Fiddler is your best choice here. You need to see what the response is from the server cache and cache time-wise. Clients also must make a request to a particular server in order for BC to update it's contents.

Answer (score 2):

What i understand Jave script files cached in the user's browser. So there are couple of workarounds which you can think about.

- Flush the Blob cache on servers( but chances are Users's browser still hold old data)
- A way to force it would be when you make a change to the script, also make a change to the reference of the script in the MasterPage (or whereever its located). [read more](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/762af0c3-05cd-4b20-9758-d64c268844dc/javascript-files-in-branding-solution-cached?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)
- [Avoiding bugs from cached JavaScript and CSS files in SharePoint](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/11/avoiding-bugs-from-cached-javascript.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the description with more info. Regarding second bullet point, each change creates a new file version.

Comment: have u tried flushing the blob cache?

Comment: that's the last resort. Still no other options so far.